# Ambiguous use of ‘subscript’ error when importing AVFoundation

Tags: xcode, swift, subscript

Using Xcode 7.2 and Swift 2.1.1

I am retrieving data from a .plist file 
The file contains data for a series of quizzes. The data for the quiz to be retrieved consists of an array of 12 questions and a corresponding array of 12 multiple choice options (4 members each).

```
var quizId = “”
var questions:[String] = []
var answers:[[String]] = []
```

The quiz id is passed in a segue from the previous view controller. Then the data is retrieved in ViewDidLoad.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(“quiz id”, ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
questions = dict!.objectForKey(“Questions”)![0] as! [String]
answers = dict!.objectForKey(“Answers”)![1] as! [[String]]
```

The code works perfectly well until I try to import AVFoundation, when the last two lines throw the ambiguous use of ‘subscript’ error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because importing AVFoundation brings up new subscript definitions (namely AUAudioUnitBusArray, thank you Martin R.) and it confuses the compiler which doesn't know what type is `dict!.objectForKey(“Questions”)` anymore (it is indeed inferred as AnyObject after the import, instead of NSArray).

The cure is to safely help the compiler to know the type, for example by doing a downcast with optional binding:

```
if let questions = dict?.objectForKey("Questions") as? NSArray {
    print(questions[0])
}
```

or even better:

```
if let questions = dict?.objectForKey("Questions") as? [String] {
    print(questions[0])
}
```

Comment: From the compiler output in the Report navigator one can see that both `NSArray` and `AUAudioUnitBusArray` have a subscript method ...

Comment: Downcasting to NSArray or [String] produces a warning: “Cast from AUAudioUnitBus to unrelated type NSArray always fails.”, and the array is not created. But downcasting to AnyObject works:) So answer accepted and thanks.