# How to resolve "ambiguous use of subscript" error?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm having an issue in Swift where my code was working perfectly fine. Upon importing the AVFoundation, I get the `ambiguous use of subscript` error for the `item`

I found the reason why from here:
[Ambiguous use of ‘subscript’ error when importing AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998108/ambiguous-use-of-subscript-error-when-importing-avfoundation)

However, I can't seem to resolve it based on the answer provided there.

Here's my code:

```
self.resultsVideoDurations_DICT = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

let item = self.resultsVideoDurations_DICT["items"] as AnyObject!

let key  =  ( ( ( item[0] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["publishedAt"] as? String)!

let value = ( ( item[0] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["contentDetails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["duration"] as? String
```

I have tried to do the following (items[0])! but that gives me the warning:

> Cast from 'AUAudioUnitBus' to unrelated type 'Dictionary' always fails

How can I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: You could try breaking each line up into multiple statements. That usually helps with the type inference system, especially if you specify which type each variable should be.

Comment: "You could try ..." – no, you *should*!

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast `item` to the type you proceed to force it to:

```
let item = self.resultsVideoDurations_DICT["items"] as! [Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>]

let key  =  ( ( ( item[0])["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["publishedAt"] as? String)!

let value = ( ( item[0])["contentDetails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["duration"] as? String
```

That appears to clear it out in a playground.